# How do I find the location of MySQL daemon error log?

Tags: mysql, linux

Many MySQL problems require examining MySQL daemon error log, but it is not always obvious where it is. One way to find it is to issue `SELECT @@log_error` query. But what if you have a root shell on a Linux MySQL server host, do not want to connect to the server, and need a quick and dirty way to grab that in a shell script?

Answer (score 1):

We can use the fact that `mysqld` uses file descriptor 2 (`stderr`) for the error log and the `/proc` file system like this:

```
sudo readlink /proc/$(pidof mysqld)/fd/2
```

this, of course, requires a currently running server. File descriptor is guaranteed to be 2 because MySQL writes to the error log via the redirection of the stderr stream to the specified log on startup, and then writing to stderr - at least in versions 5.5 and earlier, likely in later versions as well.

Comment: anything for windows ?

Comment: I only use Windows when I absolutely have to, which is rarely, but I would image the same idea would work. You will need to find which file corresponds to the file descriptor 2 of `mysqld.exe`. Maybe start with `openfiles /query` ? If I had to maintain a Windows box, the first thing I would do is install Cygwin so I would have the tools I know how to use. With Cygwin, you could probably do `lsof -p $(pidof mysqld) | grep 2w | head -1 | awk '{print $9}'`

Comment: I guess it would be in reference to answering or pointing peeps to a stack answer in all cases (which is my motivation). I will look into it (pumping something thru the daemon as a script / command line actually, preferably) vs. install. But thanks for this, cygwin thoughts, etc