# Sql databases get corrupt after every backup

Tags: mysql, sql-server, backup, innodb, myisam

I have a problem with my unix server. This started a week ago. One day after a backup (I used to keep 3 backup files) I visited a website on the server but it wouldn't work. I restarted the server and it seemed to be working fine except the mysql service. My attempts to restart it failed. Then I figured that was because the server was full, so I deleted one of the backups, cleaned up some space and the mysql service restarted successfully. Than I figured tables in one of the databases (MYIsam tables) were corrupt. So I repaired them through myisamchk command via ssh and all worked fine. However, the very next day I woke up they were corrupt again (despite mysql was working fine), and this time there was no disk space problem on the server. I repaired them again. The next day the same thing happenned; and this time innodb tables that were part of another database were corrupt as well. I've fixed them too, so now all is working well but I guess the same thing will happen after tonight's backup.

I can't identify the problem and I don't know what logs to look into to understand the problem. Can anyone please help me out? Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: What method are you using to perform the backup?

Comment: I do it through whm's new backup system, the legacy one is currently disabled. I use the compressed options and get backups of the sql databases per account only. The server details are as follows: CENTOS 6.7 x86_64 xenpv – server  WHM 11.52.1 (build 2). Do you need additional information?

Comment: Do you see anything of interest in the MySQL error log? To find the location of the log: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33700660/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-mysql-daemon-error-log

Comment: Nope, today's log starts as follows for example:

`151130  0:15:08 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './eximstats/smtp' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed
151130  0:15:08 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './eximstats/smtp' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed
151130  0:30:02 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './eximstats/failures' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed
151130  0:30:02 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './eximstats/sends' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed` @sasha-pachev

Comment: The error log is huge btw, about 25 MB... I guess that's too big for a log file.

Comment: run this as root from a shell prompt: `grep -i signal   $(readlink /proc/$(pidof mysqld)/fd/2)` . Does it find anything?

Comment: I run the command but it showed up nothing, it gave me no output message.

Comment: Also `grep sacrifice /var/log/syslog /var/log/messages` - the suspicion is that `mysqld` is killed by OOM killer when backup runs the system out of memory.

Comment: Neither systemlog nor messages folders exist in the log directory so the command gives an error. So do you think this is again due to lack of free space in the server? @SashaPachev

Answer (score 0):

No easy answer here.  My immediate thought is that the dbase is still busy when the backups commence, possibly corrupting indexes, interferring with caches, etc.  Turn on full logging and check for problems when the backup starts happens.  Maybe you will find something.

Look for the my.cnf file.  On my CentOs it is located in /etc/my.cnf.  It will have a config setting for the location of the error log.

Comment: my.cnf file is pretty empty actually... I found and checked the error log but it just starts saying xxxxx database is corrupt and automatic repair failed... The content of the cnf file is below.

`[mysqld]
innodb_file_per_table=1
max_allowed_packet=268435456
open_files_limit=10000
default-storage-engine=MyISAM`

Answer (score 0):

My strongest suspect is OOM kill by the kernel or some other issue that results from running the system out of memory. Try this:

- Start `top` on the server and press `M` to sort by memory so the biggest memory user is at the top.
- note the `pid` of `mysqld`
- manually perform the backup as you observe the value of the RES column in the `top` output (resident memory size)
- once the backup is over see if the `pid` of `mysqld` has changed

If the `pid` has changed (meaning restart took place), and you saw the memory footprint of `mysqld` take up something comparable to the total amount of system memory, then my suspicion is correct, and we need to lower some settings in `my.cnf` to make it use less memory, e.g `key_buffer_size` and `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.

EDIT - From the log you posted, there are additional issues although it is not clear how they could be contributing to the table corruption. Your server appears to be running with `--skip-innodb` and your backup script is not able to deal with the absence of `InnoDB` storage engine printing exception error messages, but nevertheless continuing. It is also attempting to do a repair, which is failing due to the lack of system privileges (error 1 is Operation not permitted). It is possible that encountering those errors triggers some faulty logic in your backup script that leaves the tables corrupted.

At this point I would recommend disabling MySQL backup using the cPanel tool, and using `mysqldump` or some other solution (e.g. Xtrabackup (https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.3/index.html)) from a cron job instead.

EDIT2 - from the test results. The manual backup does not run the system out of memory and does not crash the server. The jury is still out on the automatic one.

Comment: Ok, let me try this now. I'll update here once it's done. Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: By the way... This is yesterday's backup log. Do you see anything that might cause the problem? I thought maybe this could help.  http://textuploader.com/5xafm

Comment: So the backup has been completed according to the logs... Interestingly, the databases didn't get corrupt this time? Also, mysql pid stays the same, is that normal? It normally uses about 56M RES, during the backup it went higher (around 88M) but nothing get corrupt. I wonder if it will happen with the auto backup tonight. By the way, I ran the backup with the following code: /scripts/cpbackup --force

Looking forward to hearing your comments on this and thanks very much again for your time and effort. @sashapachev

Comment: Thanks very much for all your help. Interestingly enough, the auto backup run yesterday with no problem. I'll check if it works tonight and update here. Do you think I should fix this skip innodb issue as well?

Comment: It depends on why you put `skip-innodb` in the config to begin with. If it is very important for `mysqld` to be light-weight and not accidentally create InnoDB tables, then use a different backup solution. If not, just remove `skip-innodb` from `my.cnf` and restart MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

- Don't kill mysqld; shut it down gracefully.
- Switch from MyISAM to InnoDB; the latter does not suffer from that 'error'.