# MariaDB/MySQL resource limit was exceeded

Tags: mysql, linux, centos, mariadb, centos7

I'm trying to connect to MariaDB/Mysql installed on my CentOS 7 and get the following error when trying to connect using: `mysql -u root -p`.

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (111)

I have tried connecting to it by specifying the IP Address instead of using localhost but I get the same error.

When I try to get the MariaDB status, I get the following message (`/bin/systemctl status mariadb.service`):

> mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
>      Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
>      Active: failed (Result: resources)

And starting it yields the following error (`/bin/systemctl start  mariadb.service`):

> Job for mariadb.service failed because a configured resource limit was exceeded. See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

I also looked into the logs located at /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log

```
160408 12:21:00 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid ended
160408 16:11:01 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
160408 16:11:01 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.47-MariaDB) starting as process 3054 ...
160408 16:11:02 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160408 16:11:02 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
160408 16:11:02 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
160408 16:11:02 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
160408 16:11:02 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160408 16:11:02 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160408 16:11:02 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
160408 16:11:04  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
160408 16:11:05 Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.5.46-MariaDB-37.6 started; log sequence number 54018416776
160408 16:11:06 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
160408 16:11:07 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
160408 16:11:07 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
160408 16:11:07 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.47-MariaDB'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306 MariaDB Server
160409  6:26:06  InnoDB: Error: Write to file ./ibdata1 failed at offset 9 615514112.
InnoDB: 1048576 bytes should have been written, only 585728 were written.
InnoDB: Operating system error number 28.
InnoDB: Check that your OS and file system support files of this size.
InnoDB: Check also that the disk is not full or a disk quota exceeded.
InnoDB: Error number 28 means 'No space left on device'.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
160409  6:26:06  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 140463216400128 in file os0file.c line 4377
```

Anyone has any ideas on how to fix this error?

Thank you :)

Comment: Check mysql error log and post the relevant diagnostic from there if available. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33700660/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-mysql-daemon-error-log for a one liner to get the location of the log.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)
Since mysql/mariadb is not running I'm unable to get the logs using the recommended techniques. However I located the log file in "/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log" and added the content to my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
> perror 28
OS error code  28:  No space left on device
```

Need I say more?